# C# Edmx - update a database

Tags: c#, sql, edmx

I have a question. I have a project that uses an edmx and all hooks up fine to the sql server.
I have installed it in several servers.

What I want to know is, having made changes in development so m database and my edmx are change,s say a new table and a modified one.
How do I make it so these updates are aplied automatically when I publish an app update?
I remember once a long time ago doing code first database work and making some kind of file or procedure that would automatically apply these changes when the app ran.

Can any one fill me in again.

Comment: The keyword is "migration".

Comment: @user2864740: but migrations are **only** available in EF code-first, but if the OP has a `.edmx` file, chances are he's not using code-first ....

Comment: @marc_s Migrations are available everywhere - it's the concept of the process. It doesn't matter if it's code first, model first, database first.

Comment: @user2864740: OK - the *general concept* of migrations is available everywhere, but the **EF migrations** are only available when you use **EF code-first** ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- AFAIK, when you're using model first or database first, you can't use Migrations, you generate a DDL  script that when executed, creates the database or drops and recreates tables losing any data you had.

See [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424) read point number 5.

*"The script that is generated will drop all existing tables and then recreate the schema from scratch. This may work for local development but is not a viable for pushing changes to a database that has already been deployed. If you need to publish changes to a database that has already been deployed, you will need to edit the script or use a schema compare tool to calculate a migration script."*

What I do here, is make the changes to the database and update the model (Right click edmx designer, click "update model from database")

2.- You can configure updates on a ClickOnce installer, any changes made to the edmx will be published on your app.